# Enabling and disabling draggable elements

Tags: jquery

I'm disabling some 'li' draggable elements and then attempting to enable an 'li' element based on its id and class. 
The class is being removed but the li element is still not draggable ?

```
//Disabling draggable on li elements using 'not'
$(".myLi:not(.disable)").sortable({
revert : true,
}).draggable({
helper : "clone"                
}
});

<li id="test" class="myLi disable" >Li Point1</li>

var toTest = $('#test');

//Enabling li element to draggable again using id and class
toTest.removeClass('disable');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you add the draggable functionality only to the elements with `class` *myli* but have not the `class` *disable*. Later you remove the `class` *disable* from one element. Because it has never become the functionality, it can't be draggable.

First make all `li` draggable, then you should use the `enable` and `disable` method from `draggable`:

```
$(".myLi").sortable(...).draggable(...);
$(".myLi.disable").draggable('disable');
```

If you want to enable one:

```
toTest.draggable('enable');
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9sHz/1/).

Comment: Apologies, I've updated my question to include the 'disable' css whitin the li element. Is your answer still valid ?

Comment: Yes, you add the draggable functionality to only some of all .myli elements (which have not the class disable). Adding or removing a class doesn't changed this.